# Symfony folder structure doesn't fit to docs/tutorials with symfony/website-skeleton

Tags: symfony

I have a beginner question regarding folder structure: I started a new project based on `symfony/website-skeleton`. I don't know wether it's due to this package or if things in symfony have changed recently, but I have a different folder structure than in all the docs and tutorials.

My PHP code lives in `/src` my templates live in `/templates`.
Now the Tutorial of `FOSUserBundle` tells me I can override bundle templates by creating the folder `/app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views`, but I don't have an `/app` folder.

Where would I achieve this with my structure? Or should I somehow restructure my project to get back the `/app` folder?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer by digging more into the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/overriding.html

The correct way to override bundle template with this folder structure is: `templates/bundles/{BUNDLE_NAME}/{PATH/TO/TEMPLATE.html.twig}`

So in my case: `templates/bundles/FOSUserBundle/layout.html.twig`